# Are images viewed on my screen while using Tor/Firefox combo saved somewhere on my computer?

Tags: security, images, privacy, tor

If an image is not saved while viewing it in Tor, what happens to it when the Tor browser is shut down?  Is there a copy/thumbnail saved somewhere, or a reference to it on the hard drive?  Does a person have to erase anything when Tor is shut down?

Answer (score 2):

If you type **about:cache** in Firefox you will see the following information:

[image: 1]

Only large image and media files are stored as individual files on disk in Firefox's cache folder. Other files are stored in a few large container files and not as separate files on disk. The individual files on disk have random names without a file extension for security reasons, so you can't open an application or start a downloaded virus inadvertently by clicking a file in the cache folder.

The OfflineCache folder for portable Firefox bundled with Tor can be found at:

```
Tor\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile\OfflineCache
```

Under `Options / Privacy` **Never remember history** should be selected by default. You can also select **Use custom settings** as long as **Clear history when Firefox closes** along with *all* related settings is selected. This should ensure that nothing's retained on disk when Firefox closes. Of course the data is not securely erased/wiped from disk so it *might* be possible for a forensics expert to retrieve some or all of it from the deleted cache files, but unless you find yourself in that sort of situation it's unlikely a normal user will ever be able to tell exactly what (ahem) images you were viewing.